# Роутер-диспатчер для PHP наподобие GluePHP

Tags: php, роутер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, роутер/диспатчер для PHP наподобие [GluePHP](http://gluephp.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последнее время их много появилось

- [Moor](https://github.com/jeffturcotte/moor/) (https://github.com/jeffturcotte/moor/blob/master/README.markdown)
- [F3](http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/) (http://bcosca.github.com/fatfree/)
- [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html)
- [Slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) (http://www.slimframework.com/)
- [Какой-то там простой router](https://github.com/Th3-Night/SPR---Simple-PHP-Router) (https://github.com/Th3-Night/SPR---Simple-PHP-Router)
- [Ещё один](https://github.com/mqsoh/preg_router) (https://github.com/mqsoh/preg_router)
- [В общем много их...](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=router&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=PHP)